# Fetch data from Master table on basis of child table ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Tbl1 and tbl2, Tbl1 is master table and Tbl2 is support table. We need to fetch data from from Tbl1 with multiple SQL functions like (Contains, Like,..) on the behalf of Tbl2.

I am getting ordering only from Tbl2 to get the data from Tbl1.

```
1 Like
2 Contains
3 etc
```

Accroding to Tbl2 return, I need to perform query from Tbl 1. If I have "Like" first and "Contains" in 2nd. So my Query would be

```
Select * from Tbl1 where columnname Like '%keyword%'
Union
Select * from Tbl1 where Contains( Columnname, '%keyword%')
Union
Select * from Tbl1 where etc....
```

If we make change column order in Tbl2 then Tbl1 should be change

```
1 Contains
2 Like
3 etc
```

Tbl1 Output -

```
Select * from Tbl1 where Contains( Columnname, '%keyword%')
Union
Select * from Tbl1 where columnname Like '%keyword%'
Union
Select * from Tbl1 where etc....
```

Can anyone help me to write such types of query.

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide proper query with actual output so that the question is easier to understand?

Comment: @Vivek Viswanathan: Question is very clear. I need to generate query on Tbl2 keyword basis. If Like is first then Like will apply first in Tbl1 and if Contains is first the Contain will apply first on Tbl1. According to Tbl2 column order, write the query from master table.

Comment: "Tbl1 with multiple SQL functions like (Contains, Like,..) on the behalf of Tbl2" -> what does this mean? How can we add conditions on behalf of another table? This is not clear at all.

Comment: And what does this mean 'If I have "Like" first and "Contains" in 2nd.'?  Sample data from both tables would be helpful.

Comment: I need to apply all functions "Like", "Contains" on Tbl1 but set priority basis from tbl2 column keywords.

Comment: @viveksachan You should be aware that the order you have your select statements in your unions has no guarantee on the return order, SQL Server can return the rows in any order and will depending upon the query plan chosen. The only way to gaurantee an order is by specifying an ORDER BY clause at the end of your SELECT ... UNION ... SELECT ... ORDER BY ...

Comment: @Steve Ford I am having all aggregate keyword inside Tbl2 and perform all keyword on Tbl1 on order basis. But we need to perform all keyword to get data from Tbl1 one by one. Its not mandatory to use of Union.

Comment: @viveksachan My point stands that if you do not have an ORDER BY then SQL Server can order the results in any way that it chooses.

Comment: @Steve Ford Got it. But we are storing all aggregate keyword in my 2nd table. We need to perform one by one on Order basis. So how we pass aggregate keywords dynamically.

Comment: @Vivek Viswanathan Is it clear of still confusion :).

Comment: @VivekViswanathan did my answer help, if so then you should accept it as the accepted answer, rather than just upvote. If you accept an answer your reputation increases by +2

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a bit of work and you have to know all the potential search terms upfront:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl1
(
    ID int,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)
CREATE TABLE #Tbl2
(
    ID int,
    SearchTerm Varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Tbl2
VALUES (1, 'LIKE'), (2, '=')

INSERT INTO #Tbl1
VALUES (1, 'F'), (2, 'Fred'), (3, 'Fred Astaire'),(4, 'Simon Says')

DECLARE @keyword varchar(50) = 'Fred'

SELECT t1.*, t2.ID
FROM #Tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN #Tbl2 t2 ON t2.SearchTerm = 'LIKE'
WHERE Name Like  '%' + @keyword + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*, t2.ID
FROM #Tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN #Tbl2 t2 ON t2.SearchTerm = '='
WHERE Name = @keyword
ORDER BY t2.ID
```

Comment: @viveksachan if it works for you don't forget to accept this as the answer :)

Comment: @SteveFord: Good one. I am up voting it.

Comment: @VivekViswanathan upvoting is different from accepting the answer. If you as the questioner accept an answer you are marking it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, add an artificial column for ordering purposes:

```
Select *, 1 AS src from Tbl1 where Contains( Columnname, '%keyword%')
Union
Select *, 2 AS src from Tbl1 where columnname Like '%keyword%'
Union
Select *, 3 AS src from Tbl1 where etc....
ORDER BY src ASC
```

Comment: But we are not sure "Contains" will perform first or any other keyword. These keyword are coming from 2nd table.

Comment: The principle is the same.   You just set the values of the artificial column based on the 2nd table.

Comment: Got it. But we are storing all aggregate keyword in my 2nd table. We need to perform one by one on Order basis. So how we pass aggregate keywords dynamically.

Comment: Use the select from table 2 to construct dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks @Tab Alleman Can you elaborate or give me some idea on same?.

Comment: Just google `dynamic sql example`.   There are already lots of tutorials on the internet.